# Perform action URL is dynamically generated in PHP

Tags: php, uri

I don't know how to easily describe this, here goes nothing...

I am writing a PHP script to perform an action if the URL is a specific URL, however, the URL is /ref/[VISITOR_USERNAME]. I want to set it so that anytime the URL is /ref/[ANY_TEXT], the action will perform.

```
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/ref/' . string . '') {
    ...perform action...
}
```

How do I tell the script that if the URL is /ref/ and anything following that to perform the action?

Also, I realize there are other, probably better ways to do this, but for the sake of what I am trying to do, I need to do it this way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are using a class to handle your actions, there is a similar script in here that can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851447/mvc-reading-the-url-for-controller-and-action

Comment: Why not use a simple Regular Expression rather than String Comparison (especially, since the String is Dynamic and can be anything)? Something along these lines could be handy: **if( preg_match("#ref\/.*#", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
        // NOW, GET TO WORK CODER... ;-)
    }**

Answer (score 1):

```
if(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, 5) == '/ref/') {
  ...
}
```

Comment: So what happens when the URL is something like: ***http://mysite.tld/a-path/another-path/route/ref/string***??? In this arbitrary case, **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']** will return something like this: ***/a-path/another-path/route/ref/string*** in which case your code will fail. Additionally; if the URL was just ***mysite.tld/ref/**, Your code will still run and this may not be what he wants since **he requires that a String  exists after the trailing Slash next to ref...** like so  ***http://mysite.tld/ref/a_minimum_of_one_character***

Comment: Poiz, yes, if the path is different my `if` block will not run. That is by design and in fact exactly what the question asked for. For the second requirement I guess we can debate if "ANY_TEXT" can be the empty string or not. Might be a good idea to check for that if one wishes to do so. Your answer will also "fail" for that case, by the way, because `.*` matches the empty string; you might want to upvote centauri's answer because it fulfills both of your requirements...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for more you can build a regex:

```
if(preg_match('/\/ref\/.+/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may just want to revise your Conditional Statement like so:

```
    <?php
    // CHECK THAT THE REQUEST URL CONTAINS "ref/[ANY_STRING_AT_ALL_INCLUDING_SLASHES]"
    if( preg_match("#ref\/.*#", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
        // NOW,GET TO WORK CODER... ;-)
    }
```